# No space left on device error for a particular user

Tags: publishing, cme

The below error appears for just a particular user when he publishes certain pages.

```
Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed, Unable to persist Transaction: tcm:0-75011-66560, 
No space left on device, No space left on device, 
Unable to persist Transaction: tcm:0-75011-66560, No space left on device, 
No space left on device
```

and the publishing fails. But the same pages are successfully published when published using an admin ID. Is this some user permission issue or a storage issue? How to resolve this for the concerned user?

Thanks,
Keirthana

Update: I checked if quota management is enabled and it is NOT enabled.

Comment: can you share some more details on your setup and the error, particularly the setup of the presentation server (where the Deployer is located, as I'm guessing it is an error you get in the deployment phase)?

Comment: Could it be that the user who is getting the errors is using a different publication target than the administrator?

Comment: On what kind of pages does this error occur?

Comment: Please share more details, if you still see this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks all for the response! Somehow magically the error vanished I must say. All I tried meanwhile was restart of services and asked the user to check his permission rights for the particular folder/file which he did and confirmed that he was an admin user too.

After restart of services and about half an hour later, the user was able to publish the very same files. I still have no clue why it happened but I am just thinking if the restart cleared up anything that was hung. Please add if you feel something else was the issue and you know what it is.

Thanks,
Keirthana